# Too many parameters on Imap::new

Tags: ruby, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying the following, but `Imap::new` is complaining about too many parameters

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'
require 'net/imap'

puts "username"
username = gets
password = ask("Enter password: ") { |q| q.echo = false }

imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', {:port => '993', :ssl => true})

puts "connecting to imap server"

imap.login(username, password)
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(["NOT", "DELETED"]).each do |message_id|
    envelope = imap.fetch(message_id, "ENVELOPE")[0].attr["ENVELOPE"]
    puts "#{envelope.from[0].name}: \t#{envelope.subject}"
    i += 1
    Process.exit if i>10
end
```

Error:

```
/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1101:in `get_tagged_response': Too many arguments provided ci7if1523987wib.93 (Net::IMAP::BadResponseError)
    from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1153:in `block in send_command'
    from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:1135:in `send_command'
    from /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/imap.rb:419:in `login'
    from pull.rb:13:in main
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('host', 993, true) // host, port, ssl
imap.login('IMAP_USERNAME', 'IMAP_PASSWORD')
imap.select('INBOX')
```

btw. you're selecting the INBOX twice :)

Comment: It is not the IMAP.new that causes problem, that call i correct! It is the login call on :13. Probably username or passwd is nil.

Comment: the extra INBOX call is just me copying from another sample. when I do puts username.nil?
puts password.nil? I still get false for both?

Comment: Can you connect if you specify the user and password without the console? Just put a `username = 'user'` and a `password = 'your pass'` in front of the `login`-call